# How to decrypt a ByteString using RSA this particular way, with the criptonite library?

Tags: haskell, erlang, elixir, rsa

I have some code in Elixir/Erlang that I inhereted:

```
  res = :crypto.private_decrypt(:rsa, my_bin_data, rsa_priv_key, [{:rsa_padding, :rsa_pkcs1_oaep_padding}])
```

I want to convert it to Haskell. I'm using the **cryptonite** library and its module RSA. My question is about the parameters that have to pass to it to make it do precisely the same thing as the Elixir code does.

```
import qualified Crypto.PubKey.RSA.PKCS15 as RSA
-- [.........]

res <- RSA.decrypt None privateKey myBinData
```

What should I pass as `:rsa_padding` and `:rsa_pkcs1_oaep_padding` parameters to the function?

Comment: Did you try the respective `pad` function in that package?

Comment: @BobDalgleish there's none

Comment: Yeah, there is: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.26/docs/Crypto-PubKey-RSA-PKCS15.html and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.26/docs/Crypto-PubKey-RSA-OAEP.html

Comment: @BobDalgleish yes. How am I supposed to use it, to get the same result in the Elixir code?

Comment: You will have to understand how the elixir API works. It will also be important to set up a testing process where you can reliably determine that encrypted payloads are correctly decrypted.

Comment: @BobDalgleish that's what I am doing here - figuring that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [openssl manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RSA_public_encrypt.html), `rsa_pkcs1_oaep_padding` is

> EME-OAEP as defined in PKCS #1 v2.0 with
>   SHA-1, MGF1 and an empty encoding
>   parameter

You should use `decrypt` from the `Crypto.PubKey.RSA.OAEP` module, and use `defaultOAEPParams` with `SHA1` as the hash:

```
import qualified Crypto.PubKey.RSA.OAEP as RSA
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms ( SHA1 )

...

res <- RSA.decrypt None (RSA.defaultOAEPParams SHA1) privateKey myBinData
```